# Is 就玛丽很快不哭了 grammatically wrong?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-structure

The full sentence is

> 听了我的话，就玛丽很快不哭了。

I get confused with the position of 就: 就玛丽很快不哭了 => Only Mary will not cry soon. Is that correct?

Please help me out with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the conjunction 就 means "just" or "then", it doesn't go before noun

玛丽 is a noun

The sentence should be

听了我的话，玛丽很快(就)不哭了。 --> Mary quickly (just) stop crying

or

听了我的话，玛丽(就)很快不哭了 --> Mary (then) quickly stop crying

Edition:

Notice: When 就 means "ONLY", it does go before noun

Example: 他们都哭了，(就)玛丽不哭 --> They all cried, (only) Mary didn't

Comment: I find out this: https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Expressing_%22small_quantity%22_with_%22jiu%22. It is said that when 就 is used before the subject, it means "just one person (that subject) do sth". Can you take a look and explain to me? I may misunderstand.

Comment: @Jenny It is when 就 means "ONLY" , see my edition

Comment: I think the sentence turns out to be meaningless if 就 goes before 玛丽. So you are right!

Answer (score 1):

听了我的话，就玛丽很快不哭了 can be valid when 就 means ***only***.

The whole sentence is saying: *Hearing of my words, only Mary stopped crying soon*.  It implies that there are a few people who heard of your words, but only Mary stopped crying soon, and others not.

Comment: Without a bit imagination (about concept), the sentence may not be very correct